# How to classify data which is spiral in shape?

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning, tensorflow, regression

I have been messing around in [tensorflow playground](http://playground.tensorflow.org/#activation=tanh&batchSize=10&dataset=spiral&regDataset=reg-plane&learningRate=0.03&regularizationRate=0&noise=0&networkShape=4,2&seed=0.73263&showTestData=false&discretize=false&percTrainData=50&x=true&y=true&xTimesY=false&xSquared=false&ySquared=false&cosX=false&sinX=false&cosY=false&sinY=false&collectStats=false&problem=classification&initZero=false&hideText=false). One of the input data sets is a spiral. No matter what input parameters I choose, no matter how wide and deep the neural network I make, I cannot fit the spiral. How do data scientists fit data of this shape?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are many approaches to this kind of problem. The most obvious one is to **create new features**. The best features I can come up with is to transform the coordinates to [spherical coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system).

I have not found a way to do it in playground, so I just created a few features that should help with this (sin features). After [500 iterations](http://playground.tensorflow.org/#activation=tanh&batchSize=10&dataset=spiral&regDataset=reg-plane&learningRate=0.03&regularizationRate=0&noise=0&networkShape=4,2&seed=0.73263&showTestData=false&discretize=false&percTrainData=50&x=true&y=true&xTimesY=false&xSquared=false&ySquared=false&cosX=false&sinX=true&cosY=false&sinY=true&collectStats=false&problem=classification&initZero=false&hideText=false) it will saturate and will fluctuate at 0.1 score. This suggest that no further improvement will be done and most probably I should make the hidden layer wider or add another layer.

Not a surprise that after adding [just one neuron to the hidden layer](http://playground.tensorflow.org/#activation=tanh&batchSize=10&dataset=spiral&regDataset=reg-plane&learningRate=0.03&regularizationRate=0&noise=0&networkShape=5,2&seed=0.73263&showTestData=false&discretize=false&percTrainData=50&x=true&y=true&xTimesY=false&xSquared=false&ySquared=false&cosX=false&sinX=true&cosY=false&sinY=true&collectStats=false&problem=classification&initZero=false&hideText=false) you easily get 0.013 after 300 iterations. Similar thing happens by adding a new layer (0.017, but after significantly longer 500 iterations. Also no surprise as it is harder to propagate the errors). Most probably you can play with a learning rate or do an adaptive learning to make it faster, but this is not the point here.

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Ideally neural networks should be able to find out the function out on it's own without us providing the spherical features. After some experimentation I was able to reach a configuration where we do not need anything except $X_1$ and $X_2$. This net converged after about 1500 epochs which is quite long. So the best way might still be to add additional features but I am just trying to say that it is still possible to converge without them.

[image: Solution without additional features]

Answer (score 5):

By cheating... `theta` is $\arctan(y,x)$, $r$ is $\sqrt{(x^2 + y^2)}$.

In theory, $x^2$ and $y^2$ should work, but, in practice, they somehow failed, even though, occasionally, it works.

[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you "cheated"? How did you add these features? Did you download the playground from GitHub and modify it? Or is there a more direct way to do this?

Comment: I was wondering how to apply this hack too. Tried to do it inside browser but had no luck with that. Then I decided to fork the source code and added the new input features. You can see it [here](https://github.com/cankut/playground/commit/b982c86e0d89f42b68fcda8be70cdc78df56583f)

Answer (score 1):

You can increase no of hidden layers. Following is an example (But not very efficient)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image: vanilla tensorflow playground spiral solution]

This is an example of vanilla Tensorflow playground with no added features and no modifications.
The run for Spiral was between 187 to ~300 Epoch, depending. 
I used Lasso Regularization L1 so I could eliminate coefficients. 
I decreased the batch size by 1 to keep the output from over fitting. 
In my second example I added some noise to the data set then upped the L1 to compensate.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The [solution](https://playground.tensorflow.org/#activation=tanh&batchSize=5&dataset=spiral&regDataset=reg-plane&learningRate=0.03&regularizationRate=0&noise=0&networkShape=5,4&seed=0.84823&showTestData=false&discretize=true&percTrainData=50&x=true&y=true&xTimesY=false&xSquared=false&ySquared=false&cosX=false&sinX=true&cosY=false&sinY=true&collectStats=false&problem=classification&initZero=false&hideText=false&regularization_hide=false&numHiddenLayers_hide=false) I reached after an hour of trial usually **converges in just 100 epochs**.

Yeah, I know it does not have the smoothest decision boundary out there, but it converges pretty fast.

[image: ![0.6% test error]

I learned a few things from this spiral experiment:-

- **The output layer should be greater than or equal to the input layer**. At least that's what I noticed in the case of this spiral problem.
- **Keep the initial learning rate high**, like 0.1 in this case, then as you approach a low test error like 3-5% or less, decrease the learning rate by a notch(0.03) or two. This helps in converging faster and avoids jumping around the global minima.
- You can see the effects of keeping the learning rate high by checking the error graph at the top right.
- For smaller batch sizes like 1, 0.1 is too high a learning rate as the model fails to converge as it jumps around the global minima.
- So, if you would like to keep a high learning rate(0.1), keep the batch size high(10) as well. This usually gives a slow yet smoother convergence.

Coincidentally the solution I came up with is very similar to the one provided by [Salvador Dali](https://ai.stackexchange.com/users/2492/salvador-dali).

Kindly add a comment, if you find any more intuitions or reasonings.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Spiral Dataset Classification with Test Loss=0.000 using Playground Tensor flow]

This is the architecture proposed and tested on the playground tensor flow for the Spiral Dataset. Two Hidden Layers with 8 neurons each is proposed with Tanh activation function.

Answer (score 0):

May be you need reset all settings, and select x squared and y squared, only 1 hidden layer with 5 neurons.

[image: With 5 neurons, x squared and y squared on]